# How to create a dynamic reporting platform using .net framework

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, entity-framework-6, reporting

I recently saw a reporting application in a small firm that would enable them to create and share reports very easily in few simple steps listed below:

--Create a procedure in the database to get the relevant data for the new report.

--Login to the reporting platform as an admin.

--Choose your newly created procedure from the list of all procedures displayed inside the application and link it to the relevant User Role/group who can access this report.

--And the report will be and displayed in the chosen user's report portal.

This application was completely custom built in **.Net & MSSQL**.

As far as I know data can only be displayed on web with the help of web services or some intermediate code(MVC etc.) to link that specific data to the webpage.

But how can this application generate the code for web service and linking that data to the page by itself (if it is done in this way) to display the report.

Any advise regarding the technology/ method used or a reference to something like this will be really appreciated.

Thank you!